# Loading a XIB file to a UIView Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I have a "view" that includes a "scroll view"
I also have a "Xib" file that i want to load in that "scroll view"
How should i do this?
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://medium.com/@danstepanov/your-first-ios-app-using-interface-builder-via-xibs-xcode-7-2-swift-2-1-695d2bf5e38d